# how can i select two dates today /yesterday?

Tags: sql-server-2008, date

find the customer who placed oder **today** or **yesterday**

how can i wire a this query in **SQL**

```
table
Customer- cno,fname,lname ,address  
oder-oder_no,cno,oderdate
oderline-oder_no,product,Qty,cost
```

Comment: Please show the statement(s) you've tried already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the query you asked for

```
select * from  customer where cno in (select cno from oder where (orderdate=getdate() or orderdate = getdate()-1))
```

Comment: check the question user asked. he want only customer name. not the all details with it. so orderline is not required atall

Comment: true i got it this sub query knw if u can give me join query (natural join)

Comment: select tc.* from  customer tc join oder tod on tod.cno = tc.cno
where (tod.orderdate=getdate() or tod.orderdate = getdate()-1)

Comment: select * from Customer as c ,oder as o,oderline as ol where c.cno=o.cno and o.oder_no=ol.oder_no and o.oderdate >= getdate() -1<<< with out join key word is this query correct ? i wanna know im new –

Answer (score 0):

Select * from customer c 
join oder o on o.cno = c.cno 
join oderline ol on ol.oder_no = o.oder_no 
where oderdate >= getdate()  -  1

Comment: you mean this-- select * from Customer as c ,oder as o,oderline as ol where c.cno=o.cno and o.oder_no=ol.oder_no and o.oderdate >= getdate() - 2

Comment: join << can i know why  select * from Customer as c ,oder as o,oderline as ol where c.cno=o.cno and o.oder_no=ol.oder_no and o.oderdate >= getdate() - 2 <<<< cant i use this ? with out using join

Comment: No my statement is correct joins and all. Both accomplish the same thing however. Just different methods to perform table joins.

Comment: You are using joins. You just aren't using the join keyword.

Comment: select * from Customer as c ,oder as o,oderline as ol where c.cno=o.cno and o.oder_no=ol.oder_no and o.oderdate >= getdate() -1<<< with out join << key word is this query correct ? i wanna  know im new

Comment: To select results from multiple tables you need to join the tables on some type of data if you want you returned records to make sense. The query you perform will do a join on oder_no and cno. As will mine. Syntactially they differ however they both perform 2 table joins. Review this page:http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517(v=sql.105).aspx